# Failure in Data Transmission Between Child Activity and Parent Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm designing a multi-activity scoreboard app where each activity allows the user to keep score for a variety of sports. Currently, there are two activities. The main activity support scorekeeping for basketball while the child activity supports scorekeeping for soccer. Each activity has a button that allows the user to toggle between the two sports. I want to send data from the parent activity (basketball) to the child activity (soccer) when the user navigates to the child activity and display that data on the screen of child activity. When the user navigates back to the parent activity, I want to send that same data back to the parent activity. I used the startActivityForResult(Intent I, int requestCode) and onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) methods.

I've run multiple tests and confirmed that no data is being transmitted from the child activity to the parent activity. I'm fairly sure that onActivityResult() is not being called by Android Studio environment. I placed a log command at the very top of the method and the message does not show up in logcat. I also tried Build -> Clean Project. I closed and re-opened studio. I can confirm that data is being sent successfully from the parent method to the child method.

Here is the jumpSoccer() method which facilitates parent -> child activity switch.

```java
 public void jumpSoccer(View view) {
        /*
        TESTING: SEND BASKETBALL DATA TO SOCCER ACTIVITY
        */

        //send basketball data
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Soccer.class);
        Bundle extrasBall = new Bundle();
        //team A info
        EditText teamA = findViewById(R.id.teamA);
        extrasBall.putString(EXTRA_TEAMA, teamA.getText().toString());
        TextView scoreA = findViewById(R.id.scoreA);
        extrasBall.putString(EXTRA_SCOREA, scoreA.getText().toString());
        //team B info
        EditText teamB = findViewById(R.id.teamB);
        extrasBall.putString(EXTRA_TEAMB, teamB.getText().toString());
        TextView scoreB = findViewById(R.id.scoreB);
        extrasBall.putString(EXTRA_SCOREB, scoreB.getText().toString());
        //add basketball bundle
        i.putExtras(extrasBall);

        //soccer bundle is global variable; initialized as null and given value in onActivityResult()
        //send soccer data back
        //if(extrasSoccer != null)
            //i.putExtras(extrasSoccer);
        startActivityForResult(i, SOCCER_REQUEST);
    }
```

Here is the jumpBasketball method which facilitates child -> parent activity switch.

```java
  public void jumpBasketball(View view){

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        //get bundle sent from basketball activity and add to intent to send  back
        Bundle extrasBall = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        i.putExtras(extrasBall);
         startActivity(i);
```

*Note: getIntent() is called once before this method for reasons unrelated to this problem*

Here is the onActivityResult method which is supposed to handle the data returned from the child activity.

```java
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //receive data and populate stat page (artificial memory) for basketball data and simply hold soccer data until it is returned
        Log.d("oAR called", "success!");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //request code indicates origin of data
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SOCCER_REQUEST) {
                //get basketball bundle
                Bundle extrasBall = data.getExtras();
                //repopulate team A info
                EditText teamA = findViewById(R.id.teamA);
                teamA.setText(extrasBall.getString(EXTRA_TEAMA));
                TextView scoreA = findViewById(R.id.scoreA);
                scoreA.setText(extrasBall.getString(EXTRA_SCOREA));
                //repopulate team B info
                EditText teamB = findViewById(R.id.teamB);
                teamB.setText(extrasBall.getString(EXTRA_TEAMB));
                TextView scoreB = findViewById(R.id.scoreB);
                scoreB.setText(extrasBall.getString(EXTRA_SCOREB));

            }
        }

        }
```

I expect the parent activity to display the data from child activity but it doesn't. It seems as if onActivityResult() is not being triggered due to absence of the aforementioned log message in the logcat.

Comment: setresult is missing in your child activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child activity, use this to return to parent activity

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("bundleName", yourBundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is finish() absolutely necessary? Also, how plausible do you think it would be to create a sort of artificial memory system between the two activities by using a hand-off mechanism (i.e child activity holds parent activity when child is active and vice versa so it seems to the user that the application "remembers" the input data when he returns to an activity)?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do would be better with an activity + fragments and a shared view model approach, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing